# chrome.scripting.executeScript woes with async functions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an MV3 chrome extension on Chrome 106. I want to run an async method with `executeScript` like this:

```
async function doSomeWork() {
    console.log("starting");
    await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({foo: 'bar1'}); // call arbitrary await method
    console.log("weird, this is never seen");
    // ...do some more work
}

async function doit() {
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: tab.id}, func: doSomeWork});
}
```

The documentation seems to imply this should work:

> If the resulting value of the script execution is a promise, Chrome
> will wait for the promise to settle and return the resulting value.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#promises

However, the function never continues executing after the first `await` call. The second log message doesn't show up on the console. The sendMessage works, though.

Am I completely misreading the documentation?

A complete example is available in this git repo: https://github.com/stickfigure/chrome-extension-test/blob/master/src/app.tsx

Comment: Barring a bug in Chrome it can be simply because sendMessage throws an exception.

Comment: I updated the test code (in git) to confirm that an exception is not being thrown from sendMessage. Could it be a bug in Chrome? It seems too obvious.

Comment: Filed this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373433